# How can gcc compile multiple source files for use in GDB?

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I have two source files that I'm currently compiling into one executable.

I use `gcc -o ProgramName file1.c file2.c`

I know gdb requires the `-g` flag when being compiled but I must be placing it incorrectly. I have tried several things but nothing along the lines of:

`gcc -g -o ProgramName file1.c file2.c` is working for me. When I run `gdb` -> `run` it says that no executable was found.

How do I compile this correctly so it will run in GDB?

Comment: You did start or load the program in GDB?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? I did exactly what I described before and that's all I can say for sure.

Comment: start it like `gdb ./ProgramName` -> `run`. GDB requires an executable to run it

Comment: install eclipse, it will take this boring part. And will visualise the gdb output in the more convenient way. Command line gdb is the last resort

Comment: I appreciate the idea but I am quite familiar with NetBeans already. I'm being forced to use command line gdb for a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper command is

```
gdb ProgramName
```

followed by

```
run
```

in the prompt.

Comment: I think the `./` is redundant. `gdb` should find `ProgramName` in the current directory. This is unlike the shell, which will only search the `PATH` unless the name contains a `/`.

Comment: @IanAbbott that's true, and fixed but I just realized that gdb seems to use path too :D

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure whether it checks the current directory first or the PATH first, but it should be easy to test.

Comment: @IanAbbott at least mine is current directory first (`ln -s /bin/ls; gdb ls`)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
gdb -tui ProgramName
```

This will open the GDB with the [Text User Interface](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/TUI-Overview.html#TUI-Overview), which by default will load the source code in your screen. In this way you will know if the program was loaded.

The screen will be split, with the source code in the top and the command line in the bottom, like this:

[image: gdb-tui]

Answer (score 0):

Please compile the individual source files(cxx,c) using 
`gcc -g -c file1.c file2.c` (so on)
This will generate the file1.o file2.o files (so on ...)
now compile the object files into a formal executable.
`gcc -g -o file.exe file1.o file2.o`

On similar lines for c++
`g++ -g -c file1.c file2.c`
`g++ -g -o file.exe file1.o file2.o`

Now run the gdb file.exe

For further reference:
Please go through:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html#zz-1.7